# Windows 10 update 1709 fails on M.2 SSD

Tags: windows-10, ssd, windows-update, windows-10-v1709, m.2

I have a brand new PC with Windows 10 and since the last month, I receive error messages about the 1709 update.  The error code is 0xc1900200 which means that "machine does not meet the minimum system requirements."

This morning, the error message was a bit clearer:

> you can't install windows on a usb flash drive using setup

Since I moved the OS from a HHD to a M.2 SSD drive, is it possible that windows consider it as a USB drive?  If so, how can I let him know it's ok to install the 1709 update on it?

Comment: Sorry; missed the error; I had a similar problem.  Trying to remember where the registry key is

Comment: “is it possible that windows consider it as a USB drive?” - USB drive, no, portable install, yes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows does not allow portable installations of Windows to be updated.  This includes the installation of feature updates.

> Follow these steps to delete the Windows To Go registry value:
>
> - Open regedit.exe
> - Browse to:
>
>   ```
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
>   ```
> - Delete this value: `PortableOperatingSystem`

[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/af05f60a-4cb0-4561-b49f-71938dad6853/my-computer-thinks-its-a-windows-to-go-computer-but-its-not?forum=W8ITProWTG)

After the removal of the key Windows will allow you to perform the upgrade.

#### Additional information:

> To change the `PortableOperatingSystem` registry, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open **Registry editor** (regedit.exe)
> 2. **Locate** and the select the following registry subkey:
>
>    ```
>     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
>    ```
> 3. From the right-side pane **double-click** on `PortableOperatingSystem` Dword value
> 4. Change the value data to **0** (The default value is 1)
> 5. Close the registry editor
> 6. Restart the computer

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2778881/multiple-operations-fail-if-windows-8-is-improperly-identified-as-a-wi)