# Internal storage showing up as external

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, uefi

I've modified my registry (`TreatAsInternal`), which hasn't done the trick. Windows still thinks my drive is removable, and therefor is preventing me from updating builds as that can't be done on external drves, which it thinks mine is. What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Just one comment: removable is not the same as external.  Tons of internal devices are removable, esp higher end ones.

Comment: @Hennes In colloquial usage this is how the word is used, pedantry aside.

Comment: I know. I just tend to be very precise in computer related environments. Humans can translate/ Computers do not.  (e.g. my network card, a PCI-e card type Mellanox X2 is ejectable. Wich was weird when I first noticed it. But after thinking things through it makes sense from an OS point of view)

Comment: @Hennes I see. Do you know how I can resolve my issue, then?

Comment: What key exactly did you edit[?](https://superuser.com/questions/792693/how-can-i-remove-the-option-to-eject-internal-sata-drives-from-the-windows-8-tra)

Comment: @Ramhound `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\storahci\Parameters\Device`, but it hasn't done anything to fix it.

Comment: What is the value of *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control*; **PortableOperatingSystem**?

Comment: @Ramhound The value is `1`

Comment: @DocGolf -[It should be 0.](https://superuser.com/questions/1307539/windows-10-update-1709-fails-on-m-2-ssd/1307555#1307555)