# How to update windows 10 installed on a flash drive?

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, windows-update

I have Windows 10 installed on an external ssd. This worked fine until I recently was prompted from some programs, that I need to update my windows version. But the updater did not show any updates.

To fix that I have downloaded the latest update from the [microsoft page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). Unfortunately during install it says "You cant install windows on a usb flash drive using setup".

Ok apparently I cant install it using set-up, but is there a way to update my windows version to the latest one?

My current version is 1903 and the latest version seems to be 21H2.
I would like to keep windows on my ssd and do not have any interest to make room for it on my internal HD.

Comment: [The deletion of the key responsible for the hard block on actual Windows to Go install likely will result in the installation ceasing to be bootable.](https://superuser.com/questions/1307539/windows-10-update-1709-fails-on-m-2-ssd/1307555#1307555). You have been warned. Windows to Go installs cannot be updated. You will have to reinstall windows using an updated ISO. What you want is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although unsupported, the post
[Windows To Go (Windows 10) Upgrade to anniversary update](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9f96f44c-4c14-4a51-87c9-7123a0ad29f5/windows-to-go-windows-10-upgrade-to-anniversary-update?forum=win10itprosetup)
offers a solution.

I haven't tested this method so cannot vouch for it, but here it is:

- Download the Windows ISO
- Run `regedit`
- Navigate to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control`
- Change the value `PortableOperatingSystem` from `1` to `0`
- Reboot
- Open the ISO in Explorer and run `setup.exe`.

Comment: After some hesitation if tried it, and it worked without any problems.